# need help formating type="datetime-local" in ColdFusion (not a cold fusion element)

Tags: sql-server, date, datepicker, coldfusion, date-formatting

Ok I have searched for 2 days and thought I found the solution but it's not working maybe I can get a hand here.

I'm trying to allow the user to choose the date **and** time of their form post. I found the type="datetime-local" which achieves this (even though it's not widely supported by browsers it still seems to work for my purposes.)

form element:

`<input name="PostDate" type="datetime-local"` (the version of CF which we are using has the cfcalendar deprecated)

My `cfform` method is "post" and my action is "submit.cfm"

When we get to the submit.cfm page I'm using the following CF code to format the date to go into MSSQL database:

```
<cfset PostDate=Replace(PostDate,"T"," ","All")><br>
<cfset PostDate = DateTimeFormat (PostDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:nn:ss")>
```

and the output says that the date is formatted correctly:
[image: format code output]

But...  when I try to cfinsert the date into the database it seems like the formatted date was not saved in the #PostDate# variable (this error is being thrown by the MSSQL database server:

[image: MSSQL error thrown]

And for completeness of information this is how the table in the database is set up:
[image: database]

---

this is the code for the submit.cfm

---

```
<cfmodule template="customTags/front.cfm" >
<cfoutput>
    <p>Date before format: #PostDate#</p>
</cfoutput>
<cfset PostDate=Replace(PostDate,"T"," ","All")>
<cfset PostDate = DateTimeFormat (PostDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:nn:ss")>
<br>
<cfoutput>
    <p>Title: #PostTitle#</p> 
    <p>Date after format: #PostDate#</p>
    <p>Author ID: #UserID#</p>
    <p>Category ID: #CategoryID#</p>
    <p>Post Text: #Post#</p>
</cfoutput>
<hr>
<!--- Insert the new record --->
<cfinsert datasource="Intranet" tablename="TBL_POST">
<h1>Post Added</h1>
<cfoutput> You have added #Form.PostTitle#.</cfoutput>  
</cfmodule>
```

---

As a last qualification for this ask I need to say I'm an absolute beginner at ColdFusion (our state agency uses it) and it's been over ten years since I've written an HTML form.

I appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: The ISO 8601 datetime string format should be '2020-06-29T09:57:00' (you are missing the seconds specification). You won't have this problem with parameterized SQL queries but I have no knowledge of Cold Fusion to suggest how to do that.

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying. I'll have to dig around some more. Thx

Comment: Your problem is using `cfinsert`. Don't use it. Learn how to write the SQL to do the insert and then look into `cfqueryparam` where you can tell the JDBC driver what kind of data you are passing (string, date, float, etc.).

Also, stop using `cfform` and use standard HTML controls for your forms.

Comment: If you insist on using `cfinsert`, make sure you understand how it works.  It uses variables in the `form` scope.  Your formatting efforts are not necessarily changing the form variable.  They might be creating a new variable, with the same name, in the variables scope.  To verify this, run `<cfdump var = "#form#" abort = "true">` right after the two `cfset` commands.

Comment: Thank you everybody I will do more research on how to use SQL within CF and not rely on the <cfinsert> and I'll look into writing the <form> with out using the <cfform>

Comment: Thanks to **Dan Bracuk**  I was able to figure out a solution to this problem:

I needed to prefix PostDate with - form.
Like this:

<cfset form.PostDate=Replace(form.PostDate,"T"," ","All")>
<cfset form.PostDate = DateTimeFormat (form.PostDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:nn:ss")>

Comment: Regarding the use of `cfinsert` instead of `cfquery`, I always used `cfquery`.  However, one day, I inherited an application where `cfinsert` was used.  There was a software upgrade going on so everything had to be tested.  I tried to make that code fail by leaving some fields blank and putting apostrophes into some of the text fields.  The code never crashed.  Therefore, while I prefer `cfquery`, I can't really criticize `cfinsert`.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you using? With regards to SQL, a "date" doesn't really have a format that makes human sense. It's really just a number of ticks since some point in time, so formatting a date to see if you're entering the right thing, may not really show you what it's doing.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to **Dan Bracuk** I was able to figure out a solution to this problem:

I needed to prefix PostDate with - **form.** Like this:

```
<cfset form.PostDate=Replace(form.PostDate,"T"," ","All")><br> 
<cfset form.PostDate = DateTimeFormat (form.PostDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:nn:ss")>
```

The reason is that `cfinput` processes variables in the form scope and the original `cfset` commands created a variable in the variables scope.

Answer (score 0):

With 'yourtime' out of a postgresql db:

value="#DateTimeFormat(yourtime, 'yyyy-MM-dd')#T#DateTimeFormat(yourtime, 'HH:nn:ss')#"